# std::partition called twice for quick sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, std

What is the logic behind the two calls to std::partition from the example from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition?
I understand the high level design of the quick sort algorithm but I'm having difficulties fully understanding this implementation.

```
 template <class ForwardIt>
 void quicksort(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last)
 {
    if(first == last) return;
    auto pivot = *std::next(first, std::distance(first,last)/2);
    ForwardIt middle1 = std::partition(first, last, 
                         [pivot](const auto& em){ return em < pivot; });
    ForwardIt middle2 = std::partition(middle1, last, 
                         [pivot](const auto& em){ return !(pivot < em); });
    quicksort(first, middle1);
    quicksort(middle2, last);
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is actually mentioned on the Talk page for the page you linked: http://en.cppreference.com/w/Talk:cpp/algorithm/partition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first partition call splits our data set into two: (1) those less than the pivot on the left and (2) those greater than or equal to the pivot on the right.

The second partition splits that second set (2) into two sets: (2a) those equal to the pivot and (2b) those strictly greater than the pivot.

Then we recurse on (1) and (2b). Basically, this ensures that all the elements equal to the pivot are in the correct spots and don't have to be looked at again.

I make no guesses as to whether this is a better performing algorithm than the canonical single-partition implementation - but this is what it's doing.

---

Let's walk through an example:

```
initial array:  {3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 6, 4, 1, 4, 8, 8, 1, 6}
                                   ↑
                                   pivot

after 1st part: {3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 5, 4, 6, 4, 4, 8, 8, 6}
                             ↑
                             middle1

after 2nd part: {3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 6}
                 [-----------)           [------------)
                    recurse  ↑           ↑   recurse
                             ↑           ↑
                             middle1     middle2
```

Comment: With divide and conquer algorithms, sometimes the stuff we normally consider to belong to the next iteration can be migrated into the current iteration. The advantage, in this case, is the very elegant way in which the entire collection of equivalent pivots are removed from future accesses, as you so nicely illustrated.

Comment: (`nicely illustrated` - yes, but interval 2b should be closed on the right, too.)

Comment: So for a special case of an input with no duplicate elements, there would be no need for the second partition, correct?

Comment: @greybeard Iterator ranges are always half-open. The upper range does include all the numbers though

Comment: @Adrien With no duplicates, the second partition would be totally unnecessary, yes.